# Does the integral of voltage with time (as in AC circuits) has any physical significance in resistive circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, time, voltage

I tried to study the relationship between voltage and charge flow through a resistor (Whose rate of change with time indeed gives the current). I figured out that rate of integral of voltage with time should be directly proportional to the net charge flown through the resistor. (So if voltage is a cos wave charge flown is a sine wave). Am I correct or am I making some mistake?

Answer (score 1):

By Ohm's Law: $$I=V/R$$
Net charge flown in time t is:
$$Q=\int_{0}^t I d t=(1/R)\int_{0}^t V d t$$
From here it is clear that if voltage is a sine wave then charge flown is indeed a cosine wave and vice-versa.

Comment: Note that this is true if reactance is zero, i.e. no capacitors, inductors, etc.

Comment: The question is asked in regards to resistive circuits.

Comment: What the answer says is true, however I don’t see where’s the explanation of the physical meaning.